# How can I target files and folders in Mac OS the same way I target them in Windows despite having unique usernames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have a program that relies on various different .docx templates, browser drivers, api keys, etc. On Windows, I simply place everything in C:/Program Files and it works across all machines despite user login name. However, with Mac OS, it's a bit more frustrating... Here's how I grab my files in Windows:

```
file1 = ('C:\\Program Files\\MY TOOL\\Forms\\MYFORM\\whatever1.docx')
file2 = ('C:\\Program Files\\MY TOOL\\Forms\\MYOTHERFORMS\\whatever2.docx')
```

On Mac OS, my paths look more like this:

```
profile = /Users/MYNAMEHERE/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/.....etc
```

How can I either wildcard the part with my unique username, or target my directories more easily?

Comment: On macOS you should put such things in /Users/shared (assuming you want all users to be able to access them). Why you're putting user data in "Program Files" on Windows is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: I put everything in program files because it's my default program installation path. I'll try placing everything in /users/shared on mac os now.